# PostgreSQl, How to establish OdbcConnection in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I want to connect PostgreSQl DB to my C# project and i have found this code

```
OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("connection_string");
```

My problem is:-
  what i can use as the connection string and how to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Microsoft .NET with the PostgreSQL Database Server via ODBC

[Click Here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_Microsoft_.NET_with_the_PostgreSQL_Database_Server_via_ODBC)